# How can I set and restore FPU CTRL registers?

Tags: .net, delphi, fpu, ctrl

I can reset FPU's CTRL registers with this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326219

But how can I save current registers, and restore them later?

It's from .net code..

What I'm doing, is from Delphi calling an .net dll as an COM module. Checking the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> registers in delphi yield one value, checking with controlfp in the .net code gives another value. 
What I need, is in essential is to do this:

```
_controlfp(_CW_DEFAULT, 0xfffff);
```

So my floatingpoint calculations in the .net code does not crash, but I want to restore the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> registers when returning.

Maybe I don't? Maybe Delphi is resetting them when needed?
I blogged about this problem [here](http://blog.neslekkim.net/2008/10/fpu-issues-when-interoping-delphi-and.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
uses
   SysUtils;

var
   SavedCW: Word;
begin
   SavedCW := Get8087CW;
   try
     Set8087CW($027f);
     // Call .NET code here
   finally
     Set8087CW(SavedCW);
   end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

Same function you use to change them: `_controlfp()`. If you pass in a mask of 0, the current value won't be altered, but it *will* be returned - save it, and use a second call to `_controlfp()` to restore it later.

Comment: good idea, the problem is that I did not understand what to put in the mask etc, but the delphi method Set8087CW abowe was very nice.

Comment: Yeah... You hadn't mentioned you were using Delphi, so i assumed C/C++.